# O que fazer com casos limites de respostas erradas e que tem apoio de alguns membros?

Tags: debate, respostas, votos, respostas-erradas

Nem sei se isso dá pra considerar essa pergunta minha como duplicata, mas não consegui achar um caso que fosse parecido o suficiente no meta.

No início, lí a pergunta abaixo, achei o problema interessante e resolvi tentar responder.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10415/como-validar-cpf-no-banco-de-dados-sem-usar-stored-procedure/10419

Pra minha surpresa, apareceu uma resposta absurda, e levou o accept. Independente disso, coloquei a resposta correta (não pelo accept, mas justamente pra ter uma resposta razoável para a questão).

Até aí ainda vai, mas surgiu OUTRA resposta "incorreta nos mesmos termos" da outra. E ambas tiveram votos positivos. Tudo bem, eu sei que isso acontece, mas alertei o problema e o "perguntante" gostou mais... da ERRADA! Não é uma questão de opinião ou gosto, a resposta não valida CPFs, e a técnica usada é quase uma "lenda urbana".

O próprio "perguntante" não parece muito interessado no problema, mas o que me preocupa de fato é a comunidade acabar sendo orientada errada ao achar essas pérolas.

Qual a atitude mais correta nesse caso? Downvote? Flag? Deixar assim?

> Problema resolvido, mas vale uma lida no histórico todo como uma "aula" de SOpt, para quem não acompanhou a história. No final, as respostas problemas foram deletadas, mas dias depois, a pergunta também foi, levando a resposta que eu tinha caprichado junto. Mas felizmente a pergunta foi refeita, (e do jeito certo desta vez), então o esforço em ajudar não foi em vão:
>
> [Qual seria a forma de validar os dígitos verificadores de CPF em um DB usando apenas um SELECT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11470/qual-seria-a-forma-de-validar-os-digitos-verificadores-de-cpf-em-um-db-usando-ap)

Comment: eu negativei, comentei e sinalizei, essas respostas não fazem o menor sentido

Comment: Esse é um assunto muito válido, mas a pergunta em pauta tinha *outros* problemas que causaram esse rebu todo, infelizmente. E por conta disso foi apagada. O que é uma pena porque não era uma pergunta ruim, e a resposta do @Bacco era muito boa.

Comment: @Gabe, não era melhor _bloquear_ em vez de apagar?

Comment: @Sergio no fim foi até melhor. Saiu uma versão bem feita da pergunta desta vez!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Acho que depende da gravidade do erro. A maioria das comunidades, pelo que sei, não toma nenhuma ação drástica quando uma resposta errada é aceita e/ou bem votada. Entretanto, ao menos uma - [Information Security](http://itsecurity.stackexchange.com) - [encoraja *flagging* quando a resposta está errada](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Mistakes** - Sometimes an answer may be voted up highly despite being wrong. Downvote and comment as usual, but if it doesn't get resolved through voting, you can flag it.

Isso faz sentido num site onde o foco é a segurança - e portanto uma resposta errada seria bem danosa se acabasse por influenciar outros leitores. Mas independentemente do assunto, acho um bom *guideline* para determinar qual ação tomar:

**Quais as consequências de uma resposta errada ser seguida?** Se a resposta for: **não muito graves**, então a ação sugerida é **comentar** e **votar contra**; caso contrário, além das ações anteriores sugiro **sinalizar**, **debater no meta e/ou no chat** e **recomendar a exclusão** - não necessariamente nessa ordem.

Essa é minha opinião. Quanto à pergunta específica, creio que os comentários e os downvotes já são o suficiente - se quem chegar no site não desconfiar da resposta aceita ter `-2` (até agora; cada um que enxergar o erro vai acrescentar seu `-1`, já vi isso acontecendo antes), aí sinto muito mas não há o que fazer...

Comment: Grato pela opinião! O objetivo era esse mesmo, além da pergunta propriamente dita, eu ter uma referência de como os outros membros da comunidade enxergam o problema.

Comment: a pontuação já está bem mais baixa agora, -7 e -5, acredito que o mais importante é que todos que percebam os absurdos propostos por aquelas respostas as negativem, se elas nao forem excluidas pelo menos terão uma pontuação merecida

Comment: Usar flags para uma resposta errada é certamente um exagero na maior parte dos casos. Um moderador remover uma resposta normalmente precisa de um contexto melhor do que "a resposta não é boa". O voto é a melhor ferramenta para que qualquer um saiba como a comunidade se posiciona em relação à uma pergunta, para o bem ou para o mal.

Comment: @Gabe Concordo! Por isso ressaltei que só deve ser feito em casos mais graves. Em geral, é responsabilidade de cada um avaliar o conteúdo das respostas, e não "seguir qualquer uma que tenha sido aceita/bem votada". Não sei como é feito no security.SE, mas aposto que raramente uma resposta errada foi sinalizada como tal - se é que já aconteceu alguma vez na prática.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Exatamente. Sua resposta foi muito boa inclusive na contextualização do Security, onde uma resposta errada mas aceita é algo que pode realmente ser perigoso.

Answer (score 8):

> Qual a atitude mais correta nesse caso?

## Downvote!

A posição da comunidade está clara a estas alturas. Para quem não tem acesso a este tipo de contagens de votos:

[image: contagem de votos em primeira mão]
<sub><sup>*( imagem de outro site )*</sup></sub>

...é só visitar a [timeline do post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/10415/timeline) (`https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/POST_ID/timeline`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

É o tipo de situação que deixa uma sensação estranha e tem uma [proposta no Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178439/185667) para que Respostas Aceitas com pontuação negativa percam a primeira posição. Foi declinada, mas [a resposta do Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189424/185667) é promissora.

Answer (score 5):

A minha opinião é que todo o tópico é uma grande confusão e parece muito direccionado a um problema não evidenciado.

## A Pergunta

A pergunta não revela nenhum tipo de detalhe que permita a qualquer utilizador facultar uma solução, podendo até ser lida na sua forma genérica:

> Como validar **X** a partir de um SELECT em MySQL ?

Perguntas deste género dificilmente vão ajudar alguém no futuro e tem tendência a receber um conteúdo fraco e/ou sujeito a discussão.

Por outro lado também posso dizer que me faz alguma confusão a validação de dados numa consulta à base-de-dados! Por mais complicado que seja o cenário do autor da pergunta, uma [consulta é isso mesmo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/consultar) e não uma forma de processar e trabalhar dados extensivamente!

Digo isto com o objectivo de salientar que fica sempre uma pergunta neste cenário:

> Qual o problema que estás a ter para ser necessário validar dados numa consulta à base-de-dados?

Em suma, na minha opinião, a pergunta para estar correcta deveria espelhar o problema em mãos de forma a permitir respostas que o ajudem a resolver, ao invés da sua forma genérica que está apresentada sem grande informação!

## As respostas

As respostas apresentadas, seguem o problema da pergunta e dado o ambiente tão restrito no que respeita a informação, o que vejo são muitos votos a favor devido ao facto de as respostas estarem bem construídas! Mas são válidas? Onde estão os links para a documentação? Onde está a explicação daquilo que está a ser feito? Onde está um caso de teste para corroborar o código dado?

## [A resposta bem votada do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10419/223)

Não sei se a resposta está correcta ou não, não existi informação na mesma que me permita discernir isso.

Mesmo estando correcta, sem link para documentação oficial sobre o método correcto de validar um CPF, como saber ali, ao ler a mesma, que as "contas" estão a ser realizadas de forma correcta?

Acredito que o @Bacco saiba do que está a falar e tenha respondido com uma solução que funciona e faz o pretendido, mas a resposta carece ser corroborada por documentação para que não restem duvidas e assim permita aos "ignorantes sobre o CPF", como é o meu caso, avaliar e fornecer um voto.

---

## Ajudar para ser ajudado

Após uma pesquisa, encontrei [CPF: Cadastro de Pessoas Físicas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_Pessoas_F%C3%ADsicas). Assumo que o problema em mãos na pergunta indicada se refira a este número e a sua validação.

Sou Português de Portugal, deverei colocar perguntas sobre validação de códigos específicos a Portugal de uma forma que só os Portugueses de Portugal é que vão entender do que falo ? Se assim for, como vou tirar proveito do SOPT e do elevado número de especialistas em Programação que me podem ajudar a fazer as "contas" de forma correta? Ou até ajudarem-me a ver que o meu problema foi mal analisado e solução que procuro é outra?

---

## Respondendo à tua pergunta

Como já muito bem [respondido pelo @mgibsonbr](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1118/223), a forma de agir depende muito do problema encontrado.

- A pergunta está incompleta

  Neste caso em particular, na minha opinião, a pergunta carece mais informação para que possa ser facultada uma resposta que vá de encontro com o problema que o autor tem.
- As respostas estão incompletas

  As respostas carecem detalhes e links que corroborem a veracidade das mesmas, já não é a primeira vez, não será a última, que coloco uma resposta e quando posteriormente vou validar e aplicar links sobre o que apresentei como solução, apercebo-me que estava errado na abordagem inicial e tenho que rever a solução.

  Pelo que vejo, nas respostas excluídas não existiu este cuidado. Se assim foi, para que responder em primeiro lugar se não vamos verificar ou corroborar o que apresentamos?
- Os Up-Votes são a metro

  A resposta tem muita informação e tem código, o autor da resposta diz que funciona, então deve estar bem, vou dar Up-Vote.

Nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10415/como-validar-cpf-no-banco-de-dados-sem-usar-stored-procedure#comment18407_10415), vejo o @mgibsonbr a ir "mais além" e a lutar para ajudar o autor da pergunta a entender que ele está a validar a informação de forma incorrecta e que a solução que ele considerou válida está a falhar.

A minha análise sobre este assunto pode estar errada, mas estando correcta, a minha solução é "matar o problema pela raiz", votar para fechar a pergunta que está com tantos votos a negativo quantos a positivo.

Contudo, acredito que alguém mais familiarizado com o CPF pode editar a pergunta e torna-la mais proveitosa para o futuro, o que pode beneficiar o tópico e até trazer um pouco clareza ao mesmo.

Comment: Grato pela resposta, @Zuul. Acho pertinente agora "arrumar a casa", estava aguardando uma providência para poder decidir o que fazer, mas agora que a resposta que estava dando problema foi excluída, creio que dê pra fazer a melhora sugerida quanto à documentação do CPF. Quanto à pergunta, vou aguardar mais um instante "a poeira baixar" antes de mexer, visto que além de me empenhar para ajudar, o autor simplesmente me dirigiu uma série de absurdos, e não quero fomentar mais confusão.

Comment: só pra complementar, vou aguardar um instante pra editar a minha também, pois estou quase no limite do post virar community wiki (por quantidade de edições), então vou fazê-lo de cabeça fresca para mudar tudo que puder fazer pra melhorar em um edit só. Caso tenha interesse, http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpf . Não estranhe algumas pequenas diferenças nos algoritmos, pois usei uma otimização que deixa mais fácil adaptar a rotina tanto para verificar se é verdadeiro, quanto simplesmente calcular os dígitos.